# How can I show the image my api returns in js/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I want to show a pdf file from a GET request on a HTML page using plain Java Script.
The api returns a pdf-file.
This is the postman response of the api:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
function getImg() {
    var url = "https://api.herokuapp.com/download"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('token'));
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var responseObject = this.response;
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage = this.response;
        document.body.appendChild(myImage);
    });
}
```

I get this error:

TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

How can this be done?
Any help is very appreciated.
BR KRESTEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve this:

```
function getImg() {
    var url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3167fa1b890ffe735393de7d6296e32d?s=58&d=mm&r=g"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    // xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('token'));
    // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            let blob = this.response;
            let myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.body.appendChild(myImage);
        }
    });
}
```